# How to automatically store row created date and update date (of any cell in a row) into separate cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA code on a Excel sheet where I can automatically insert the created date (once data is being inserted in a row) and updated date (once any cell value of the row change from the previous value).
I tried the code below, I can get the created date but the not the update date.

I get this error

> Type mismatch

on the line:

```
If Cells(Target.Row, i).Value <> PrevVal(Target.Row, i) Then
```

I guess the problem is that I don't know how to capture properly the previous value of a cell in order to compare it with the new value.

For reference: my table is like this:

```
Id  Position1   Position2   DATE Created    Date updated    Data1   Data2 ....
```

---

```
Dim PrevVal As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ExitGraceFully
    If Selection.Rows.Count = 1 And Selection.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        PrevVal = Selection.Value
    Else
        PrevVal = Selection
    End If
    ExitGraceFully:
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target) Is Nothing Or Not 
        Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 2) & Cells(Target.Row, 3)

        If Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = "" Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = Date & " " & Time
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        End If
    End If

    Dim i As Integer
    If Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        For i = 2 To 50
            If Cells(Target.Row, i).Value <> PrevVal(Target.Row, i) Then
                Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = Date & " " & Time
                Cells(Target.Row, 5).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `i` loop is checking numerous cells but you are only changing one? If so, you could change `PrevVal(Target.Row, i)` to `PrevVal`. And replace your references to `Selection` with `Target`.

Comment: @SJR I am looping through all the columns, if there is any change that happens in any cell of that row, then the Update Date should change.

Comment: @SJR I tried changing Selection to Target. It gives me error 28: Out of Stack Space

Comment: Note that the [macros] tag says "***DO NOT USE for VBA / MS-Office languages. Use the respective [vba] tags instead.*** A macro is a rule or pattern that specifies how a certain input sequence (often a sequence of characters) should be mapped to an output sequence (also often a sequence of characters) according to a defined procedure."  I have removed that tag as it is not relevant to this question.

Comment: I suppose what I''m asking is if you are changing a cell in column B or C why do you have to check 50 other columns - why would those values have changed? The error 28 I imagine is arising because you need to disable events before changing cells. Otherwise your code will enter an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

I finally corrected my code and now it's working well.

```
Dim PrevVal As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ExitGraceFully
    If Selection.Rows.Count = 1 And Selection.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        PrevVal = Target.Value
    Else
        PrevVal = Target
    End If
ExitGraceFully:
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("B:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then

    Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 2) & Cells(Target.Row, 3)

If Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = "" Then
Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = Date & " " & Time
Cells(Target.Row, 4).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
End If
End If


If Not Intersect(Range("F:Z"), Target) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
If (PrevVal <> "") And (Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value <> PrevVal) Then
Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = Date & " " & Time
Cells(Target.Row, 5).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
End If

End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @userZZZ, this is exactly what I was looking for!
I adapted your code to my requirements and added another constraint to change the date also when the content of a cell is deleted. I noticed that the code only works for single cells, but not for multiple cells. I might work on that sometime, but for now this is sufficient.

Edit: I added the possibility to manipulate multiple cells at once and update the date for all the corresponding rows. It still doesn't work for copy/paste of multiple cells though. For that purpose, I added an error message. Alternatively, the copy/paste mode can simply be deactivated by adding "Application.CutCopyMode = False" right at the beginning of the first function.

```
    Dim PrevVal As Variant
    Dim Block_rows As Integer
    Dim Date_column As Integer

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

        On Error GoTo ExitGracefully

        If Selection.Rows.Count = 1 And Selection.Columns.Count = 1 Then
            PrevVal = Target.Value
        Else
            PrevVal = Target
        End If
    ExitGracefully:
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Date_column = 9
        Block_rows = 8

        On Error GoTo ErrorMessage

        'Select and change single cell
        If Not Intersect(Range("A:H"), Target) Is Nothing And Target.Row > Block_rows Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Selection.Rows.Count = 1 And Selection.Columns.Count = 1 Then
                'Update date if value changes or is deleted
                If (Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value <> PrevVal) Or _
                (Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = 0 And PrevVal <> 0) Then
                    Cells(Target.Row, Date_column).Value = Date
                    Cells(Target.Row, Date_column).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
                End If

            'Select multiple cells, but only change single cells
            ElseIf (Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value <> PrevVal(Target.Row - Selection.Row + 1, Target.Column - Selection.Column + 1)) And _
            (Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value <> 0) Then
                Cells(Target.Row, Date_column).Value = Date
                Cells(Target.Row, Date_column).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"

            'Delete multiple cells at once
            Else
                For RCount = 0 To Target.Rows.Count - 1
                    For CCount = 0 To Target.Columns.Count - 1
                        'Blank rows
                        If (Cells(Target.Row + RCount, Target.Column).Value = 0 And PrevVal(RCount + 1, CCount + 1) = 0) Then

                        'Delete cells or rows
                        ElseIf (Cells(Target.Row + RCount, Target.Column).Value = 0 And PrevVal(RCount + 1, CCount + 1) <> 0) Then
                            Cells(Target.Row + RCount, Date_column).Value = Date
                            Cells(Target.Row + RCount, Date_column).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
                        End If
                    Next CCount
                Next RCount
            End If
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub

    ErrorMessage:
        MsgBox ("This function is not supported for the automatic update of the date.")
        Resume Next

    End Sub
```